# Permission denied (publickey)fatal:Coul not read from remote repository.Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: github, git-clone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRXfV.png)
When I try to clone from gitlab repo it's giving permission issue.I added ssh to the gitlab profile.

I try to clone from gitlab repo it's giving permission issue.I was expecting clone respective repository.

Answer (score 0):

I changed ssh key public key name that's why it was not working..keep the default.It should work.(works for me)

Answer (score 0):

There could be following reasons to it:

1. Your SSH key configuration is not right, do SSH configuration if you haven't already or check for any possible mismatch in the configuration.
2. You might not have access to the repository or maybe some token related issue might be there.
3. Check your internet connection and try cloning again.
4. Check the connection of the local repository with the remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

It is precisely what it says it is. You are trying to access something, you don't have access to. In case you are trying to access one of your private repositories, try to check if the correct public key is added. If it is a private repository of others, you should ask them for permission.